# keypad decreases the screen Height issue - codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I have TextField in a form and when it is focused, a keypad appears. Now if I touch back command with this keypad on, the screen height decreases. 
I have some padding adjusted with respect to screen height. So the keypad affects the adjustments. And if I again go to the form with textField and touch back  icon without having keypad on, the adjustments are alright then. How to solve it?

search textfield in a form

```
Container searchContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
f.add(searchContainer);

searchTextFieldGroup = new TextField();
searchContainer.add(searchTextFieldGroup);
searchTextFieldGroup.setHint("SEARCH TABLES");
searchTextFieldGroup.setUIID("tableSearchTextField");
searchTextFieldGroup.getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_ITALIC, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
searchTextFieldGroup.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
searchTextFieldGroup.getAllStyles().setMargin(2, 2, 2, 2);
searchTextFieldGroup.getAllStyles().setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
searchTextFieldGroup.getHintLabel().getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_ITALIC, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
searchTextFieldGroup.getHintLabel().getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xcccccc);
```

Main form where the screen height changes if keypad is on or off in above form

```
screenWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
screenHeight = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();

Container menuContainer;
(mainContainer code......)

int excessHeight = Math.max(screenHeight - t.getPreferredH() - menuContainer.getPreferredH(), 0);
int excessWidth = Math.max(screenWidth - menuContainer.getPreferredW(), 0);
menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.TOP, excessHeight / 2);
menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.BOTTOM, excessHeight / 2);
menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.LEFT, excessWidth / 2);
menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.RIGHT, (excessWidth / 2));
f.revalidate
```

back btn clicked with keypad off.............backed with keypad on

[image]   .......  [image]

how to add the height cancelled by device keyboard?

```
f.addSizeChangedListener(e -> {
    screenWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
    screenHeight = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();

    int excessHeight1 = Math.max(screenHeight - t.getPreferredH() - menuContainer.getPreferredH(), 0);
    int excessWidth1 = Math.max(screenWidth - menuContainer.getPreferredW(), 0);
    menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.TOP, excessHeight / 2);
    menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.BOTTOM, excessHeight / 2);
    menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.LEFT, excessWidth / 2);
    menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.RIGHT, (excessWidth / 2));
        //Dialog.show("size change", "width " + screenWidth + " height " + screenHeight, "ok", null);
});
```

orientation listener is cancelled out by sizeChangeListener. How to fix it?

```
f.addOrientationListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        if (Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
            screenWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
            screenHeight = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();

            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);

            int excessHeight = Math.max(screenHeight - t.getPreferredH() - menuContainer.getPreferredH(), 0);
            int excessWidth = Math.max(f.getWidth() - menuContainer.getPreferredW(), 0);

            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.TOP, excessHeight / 2);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.BOTTOM, excessHeight / 2);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.LEFT, excessWidth / 2);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.RIGHT, (excessWidth / 2));
        } else if (!Display.getInstance().isPortrait()) {
            screenWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
            screenHeight = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();

            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);

            int excessHeight = Math.max(screenHeight - t.getPreferredH() - menuContainer.getPreferredH(), 0);
            int excessWidth = Math.max(f.getWidth() - menuContainer.getPreferredW(), 0);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.TOP, excessHeight / 2);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.BOTTOM, excessHeight / 2);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.LEFT, excessWidth / 2);
            menuContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.RIGHT, (excessWidth / 2) - 5);
            f.revalidate();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add screenshots and code? it's not clear from the description what you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi @Chen I have added code and screenshots. I have added the padding to make the container at the center of the form. Plus I need the height and width of the container equal to the screen height and screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely the size is changed when the keyboard is opened and you get a very small value for the `excessHeight`.
Put the same code (the 2nd block) on your Form sizeChanged() clause.

Comment: Putting code (2nd block) in sizeChangedListener doesn't do anything. I think I need to add the height cancelled by keyboard in sizeChanged method. how can I get the keyboard height? I have orientation listener in the form as well but when I added sizechangeListener, the orientation listener doesn't work. Why is that. I have added the code in the question.

Comment: Hi the sizechangedListener changes orientationListener as well. Is there any work around? I wonder if I can auto close the keypad when back button is clicked, the problem will be solved. How can I do that

Comment: The approach you picked for positioning is problematic since the screen size can change with device orientation or in newer devices with multi-tasking (muti window/split screen etc.). I would suggest wrapping the container in an absolute center border layout which will place it in the center and auto adapt to size change behaviors.